# _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Duplicate key name 'locationid_index'

Tags: mysql, reference, foreign-keys, primary-key

Referring the two foreign keys with same primary key in different table causes error in accessing

```
    # Create the 'rides' table if it doesn't exist
    cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rides (
            rideid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            driverid INT NOT NULL,
            drivername VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            from_location_id INT NOT NULL,
            to_location_id INT NOT NULL,
            date date NOT NULL,
            time datetime NOT NULL,
            available_seats INT NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY (driverid) REFERENCES users(userid),
            FOREIGN KEY (from_location_id) REFERENCES locations(locationid),
            FOREIGN KEY (to_location_id) REFERENCES locations(locationid)
            );
    ''')
```

1061 (42000): Duplicate key name 'locationid_index'
cmd_query self._cmysql.query(
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Duplicate key name 'locationid_index'

Creating a python tkinter project